# Difference between H.264 and x264 and how to play it

Tags: video, kodi, faq

> **Disclaimer**: This is not an actual question, but rather ["share your knowledge, Q&A-style"](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2011/07/its-ok-to-ask-and-answer-your-own-questions/)

So, I'm running Xbmc on my Raspberry Pi and I'm having trouble understanding what I can actually play with it and what not.

I read the RPi can play **H.264** encoded videos, but I can only find **x264** encoded videos. Will that work, too? And if so, why won't *some* files work probably?

Answer (score 42, accepted):

There seems to be a lot of misunderstanding around what H.264 (with a dot) actually is. So, quoting from [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/H.264/MPEG-4_AVC):

> H.264/MPEG-4 Part 10 or AVC (Advanced Video Coding) is **a *standard* for
>   video compression**, and is currently one of the most commonly used
>   formats [...]

The important part to stretch here is that it's only a *standard*. That means, videos are not actually encoded with H.264, but with a codec that meets the H.264 standard. One of the most common ones is [x264](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X264) (lower-case x, no dot):

> x264 is a free **software library for encoding video streams into the H.264**/MPEG-4
>   AVC format.
>   
> [...]
>   x264 implements a large number of features compared to other H.264 encoders.

So, H.264 is kind of an Interface and x264 is an Implementation (with the actual functionality) of that interface.

**So, the Pi will play x264 encoded files just fine.**

---

Then **why do some x264 encoded files not play smoothly but stop every 4-6 seconds** (depending on the amount of GPU-Ram)?

Most of the time, **it's the sound**. Since x264 is an encoder for HD video files, most of those files come with a digital high-quality sound-track, which uses the [DTS-codec](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DTS_%28sound_system%29#DTS_audio_codec).

The Pi is (at the moment) not able to hardware-decode the DTS-track and it's CPU is not powerful enough. There is a discussion about this [on the official Forums](http://www.raspberrypi.org/phpBB3/viewtopic.php?t=15546) which is worth looking into.

To find out if this is the case for you, you can use the `mediainfo`-tool (must be installed, package-names depend on your distro):

```
[tv@raspberry]$ mediainfo some_random_movie.mkv 
# Shortened output!
Audio #2
ID                                       : 3
Format                                   : DTS
Format/Info                              : Digital Theater Systems
Codec ID                                 : A_DTS
```

You now have two options:

1. Buy a DTS-capable receiver (maybe your TV can do it, too?) and [enable "pass-through"](http://wiki.xbmc.org/index.php?title=Raspberry_Pi/FAQ#Video_and_audio_formats_the_Raspberry_Pi_can_playback) (last point) in Xbmc (or whatever player you're using).
2. Convert the DTS-Tracks to AC3, which can be passed through (faster) or CPU decoded.

To find out what your receiver (the thing you plugged your HDMI-cable in) is capable of, use the `tvservice`-tool (which is not in the PATH, so you'll need the full path):

```
[tv@raspberry ~]$ /opt/vc/bin/tvservice -a
     PCM supported: Max channels: 2, Max samplerate:  48kHz, Max samplesize 24 bits.
     AC3 supported: Max channels: 6, Max samplerate:  48kHz, Max rate  640 kb/s.
```

As you can see, my current receiver is capable of decoding PCM and AC3 (not DTS).

My solution to this problem is to convert the Audio-Tracks which are DTS to AC3. Here is a small one-liner that converts **all** audio-streams in `infile.mkv` to AC3 and doesn't touch the video:

> **[ffmpeg](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/FFmpeg)**:
>
> ```
> ffmpeg -i infile.mkv -map 0 -codec:v copy -codec:s copy -codec:a ac3 outfile.mkv
> ```
>
> ---
>
> **[avconv](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Libav)**:
>
> ```
> avconv -i infile.mkv -map 0 -vcodec copy -acodec ac3 -ab 256k outfile.mkv
> ```
>
> ***Note:*** The above command also sets the **bit-rate for the resulting AC3 encoded audio-stream** (which is necessary, it seems). While 256kbps is
>   reasonably good (most DVD's use 192kbps), you might want to
>   in/decrease it.

Luckily, this takes only around 5 minutes (depending on your hardware, of course). As a little bonus, your file becomes smaller and if you're not an [Audiophile](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Audiophile), you won't hear a difference.

---

**Still, 1080p FullHD Movies are stuttering**, the screen goes black for a few seconds with no sound but the video-playback seems to continue. The Movie is H.264 encoded in an MKV container with AC3 tracks. What is the problem?

Most likely, there is nothing wrong with the movie-file, but with your Xbmc settings. In my case, the **problem was the "refresh rate" of Xbmc**. This is set to 60Hz by default. For 720p and any other small video files, this seems to not be a problem for the Pi, but 1080p files result in the above problem.

Lower the [refresh-rate](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Refresh_rate) to something less than 60Hz (at least 24Hz are sufficient for Movies). There are two options here:

1. Global Xbmc (including Xbmc itself): `System -> Settings -> System -> Video output -> Refresh rate`
2. Movies only (determined by video-file): `System -> Settings -> Video -> Playback -> Adjust display refresh rate to match video`

After lowering the refresh rate, **1080p movies should also play just fine.**

Comment: Very possibly the best answer on RaspberryPi.stackexchange.com.

Comment: Oh also I see that ffmpeg is even available for the RPI. `sudo apt-get install ffmpeg`. Have you tried this on the RPI? Does it work well?

Comment: @VincentP I haven't tried that, but I guess it will be very slow since this is a CPU intense operation.

Comment: `ffmpeg` seems to be deprecated and recommends `avconv` instead.

Comment: @Raphael no, it's not: http://stackoverflow.com/a/9477756/717341

Comment: @LukasKnuth Well, it is, depending on which flavor of `ffmpeg` you have installed? I guess everybody has to look into their `ffmpeg` output to see what they are stuck with. Thanks for the pointer, anyway.

Comment: @Raphael it depends on your distro. In ArchLinux, I don't see this problem.

Comment: @Raphael I updated the question, because it seems that the step towards `avconv` is deprecated for me now, too.

Comment: @LukasKnuth good answer except `ffmpeg` is not deprected. `avconv` is a fork.

Comment: @aergistal been meaning to update that for some time. Although I remember there was quite some confusion about this at the time that I wrote it.

Comment: Looked promising, but I got nothing but a blank line of output from `mediainfo` when giving it an .mkv. When giving it a text file, like an .nfo, it did show some info.